# Calculating vector x using backward substitution for upper triangular matrix given matrix 'a' and matrix 'b'

Tags: c

According to the pdf mentioned in below link, i need to calculate matrix 'x' given matrix 'A' and
matrix 'b' for upper triangular matrix using backward substitution.

**link: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~haber/math315/chap3.pdf**

Actually i need to use 1 dimensional array only. I have also developed logic for it and tried to
compile it, but actually it is having few errors of 'expression' and 'initialization'
    |1  2  3|     |x0|      |b0|
    |0  4  5|  x  |x1|  =   |b1|
    |0  0  6|     |x2|      |b2|
equations:
    1) 6*x2 = b2
    2) 4*x1 + 5*x2 = b1
    3) 1*x0 + 2*x1 + 3*x3 = b0

---

```
This is my code:
//here: 's' is size of matrix eg: for 3x3 it is 3
//x[] i need to get the result
//b[] it is to be multiplied with cm to get 
//cm[] is the matrix which will be multiplied with b[] to get x[]

    for(int p=s-1; p>0; p--)
        { 
        if(p==s-1)
            {
            x[p] = b[p]/cm[s*s];                        // computing x2
            }
        else
        {
                for(int j=0; int k=s-p; j<s-i; k>0; j++; k--)
                    {
                        c[p]+ = cm[s*p - j]*x[p+k];
                }
            }

        x[p] = (b[p] - c[p])/cm[s*p-(s-i)];
        }
Errors: 
1) variable 'x' may not be initialized
2) variable 'c' may not be initialized
3) expression for(int j=10; intk=s-p;j<s-i;k>0;j++;k--) has no effect
4) expected a ")" in point 3.
5) expected an expression in line  c[p]+ = cm[s*p - j]*x[p+k];
6) variable 'x' was set but never used

Please help me how to solve these errors?
Also let me know is my logic correct?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the answer is still needed. The rough idea of the code is correct, but you have some undefined variables (like **i**) and some mistakes regarding to operations with column-major matrices: the line

```
x[p] = b[p]/cm[s*s];
```

must be actually:

```
x[p] = b[p]/cm[s*s- 1];
```

as long as we are talking in C. Anyway, I just post the code that works:

```
void backward_substitution (double *A, double *b, double *x, int rows)
{
//here: 'rows' is size of matrix eg: for 3x3 it is 3
//x[] where we put the result of backward substitution
//b[] it is the vector to be used.
//A[] is the square triangular matrix.

register int i,j;

// x(m,1) = b(m)/A(m,m); %% this is for the last row.
x[rows-1] = b[rows-1]/A[(rows-1)*rows + (rows-1)];

// for i = m-1:-1:1     % i starts at 2, end at 4, w/ steps of 1
//    x(i,1) = ( b(i)- A(i,i+1:m)*x(i+1:m))  /  A(i,i);
// end

 for (i=(rows-2); i>=0; i--)
    {
      x[i] = b[i];        
        for (j=i+1; j<rows; j++)
        {
             x[i] -= A[(j)*rows + i]*x[j];
        };             
      x[i] = x[i] / A[(i)*rows + i];
    }; //for (i=1; i<rows; i++)
}; //void forward_substitution(double *A, double b*, int n)
```

For your convenience, the comments contain actual implementation in MATLAB. Enjoy.

Comment: There' a slight error in your code: should be `x[i] -= A[(i)*rows + j]*x[j];` instead of `x[i] -= A[(j)*rows + i]*x[j];` (we want to take `i`th row, `j`th column.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether you have declared your variable or not if not then please do that and you should write your second `for` loop like i have written below...

```
for(int j=0,int k=s-p; j<s-i, k>0; j++, k--)
```

because more than one initialization,condition and increment must be separated by comma.

Comment: Thanks, i have done with the changes you have mentioned. Also I have declared the variables appropriately; still it is showing 1 error and 3 warnings:
Error: Expected an expression in x[p] = (b[p] - c[p])/cm[s*p-(s-i)];
Warning: 
1)expression for(int j=0,int k=s-p; j<s-i, k>0; j++, k--) has no effect
2) variable 'x' was set but never used
3) variable 'k' was declared but never referenced...
How to solve these single error and 3 warnings?

Comment: ok @robot...the error it is giving may be because you are missing some opening or closing parenthesis and after dividing two value what type of value you are trying to store in x[p],i mean integer,float etc...May be you can try one thing keep `b[p]-c[p]` in some variable and same for `s*p-(s-i)` then try to print their values..then check you division result...

Comment: actually I am able to run the code but still warning is coming when compiling the code, that "expression for(int j=0,int k=s-p; j<s-i, k>0; j++, k--) has no effect"
can you let me know,
a)what it means?
b)and how to sort it out?
actually I feel that for size of input matrix more than 5000, the results of backward substitution, will won't work properly..
c)How this warning may hinder my output?

Comment: I have got something to solve your problem.You should not use `int` twice in your `for` loop.try this.`for(int j=0,k=s-p; j<s-i, k>0; j++, k--)`

Comment: i have already incorporated that change, and not declared anywhere else...still getting same warning messages..
what should i do?

Comment: I am not sure about this but may be you can try this `for` loop in a separate demo program and see whether it is working correctly or not and then try to debug the problem.I am sure that we are missing something that we can only catch my running every step separately...Can you please try that? otherwise we will find the other way..